Is the Left Multiplication Operator Decomposable?
Let $A$ be a unital $C^* $-algebra and $a \in A$, define the map $M_a: A \rightarrow A$ by $m_a(b) := ab$.

Is the map $m_a$ decomposable in the sense of Haagerup in [1] and does it verify $\|m_a\|_{\text{dec}} \leq \|a\|$?

For convenience, I will give the necessary definitions here.
Definition A linear map $\varphi:A \rightarrow B$ is said to be decomposable if it is a finite linear combintation of completely positive operators.
It can be seen that this is equivalent to saying that there exist $\psi_1,\psi_2: A \rightarrow B $ such that
$$
    \Psi(a) = \begin{bmatrix}
        \psi_1(a) & \varphi(a) \\
        \varphi(a^* )^* & \psi_2(a)
    \end{bmatrix},
$$
is completely bounded. Letting $\widehat \varphi(a):= \varphi(a^*)^*$ The norm  $\| \cdot \|_{\text{dec}}$ is then defined as
$$
\|\varphi\|_{\text{dec}} := \inf\left\{\max\{\|\psi_1\|,\|\psi_2\|\}: \Psi = \begin{bmatrix}
        \psi_1 & \varphi\\
        \widehat \varphi & \psi_2
    \end{bmatrix} \text{ is completely positive.} \right\} 
$$
I have tried using the polarization identitity
$$
ab = \frac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{k=1}^4 i^k(a^* + b)^*(a^* + i^kb)
$$
but it quite doesn't get the desired shape.
It might be worth to remark that if $\psi_1,\psi_2$ are as above then $\varphi = \varphi_1 - \varphi_2 + i(\varphi_3 -\varphi_4)$ where
$$
 \begin{cases}
    \varphi_1 = \frac{1}{4}(\psi_1 + \psi_2 + \varphi + \widehat\varphi), \\
    \varphi_2 = \frac{1}{4}(\psi_1 + \psi_2 - \varphi - \widehat\varphi), \\
    \varphi_3 = \frac{1}{4}(\psi_1 + \psi_2 - i\varphi + i\widehat\varphi), \\
    \varphi_4 = \frac{1}{4}(\psi_1 + \psi_2 + i\varphi -i \widehat\varphi). 
  \end{cases}
$$
and each $\varphi_i$ is completely positive.
EDIT: Replaced "finite sum" with finite linear combination in the definition of decomposable map as it was remarked by @BenGrossmann.

[1] Haagerup, Uffe, Injectivity and decomposition of completely bounded maps, Operator algebras and their connections with topology and ergodic theory, Proc. Conf., Buşteni/Rom. 1983, Lect. Notes Math. 1132, 170-222 (1985). ZBL0591.46050.

If a post seems weird, most of the times the writer is to blame, in this case me. I meant that a decomposable operator is a finite linear combination of completely positive maps and not a finite sum.

Another two things that are incorrect: $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ should have codomain $B$ instead of $M_2(B)$. (It’s $\Psi$ that has codomain $M_2(B)$.) And the definition of $|\cdot|_{\text{dec}}$ should use infimum, not supremum.

You’re using the polarization identity on the wrong thing. Instead, the correct thing to do is,
$$m_a(b) = ab = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k(a+i^k)b(a+i^k)^\ast$$
from which decomposability immediately follows. For the norm estimate, we assume WLOG that $\|a\| = 1$. Then we may let $\psi_1: A \to A$ be given by $\psi_1(b) = aba^\ast$ and $\psi_2: A \to A$ be the identity map, both of which have norms at most $1$. Then,
$$\Psi(b) = \begin{pmatrix} aba^\ast & ab \\ ba^\ast & b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} b \begin{pmatrix} a \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}^\ast$$
is completely positive, so $\|m_a\|_{\text{dec}} \leq 1$, as required.

The polarization identity I was using proved that the operator was decomposable but I was having troubles with the norm estimate. Thank you a lot! Also for the corrections.

@TomásPacheco The problem with your decomposition is that it's not clear (from the nature of the sum, at least) that you're describing a linear map over $b$. David's sum gives a Kraus decomposition for the operator

@TomásPacheco Indeed, as Ben mentioned, the polarization identity you used does not yield linear maps of $b$, let alone cp maps of $b$. Though something similar would have worked if, instead of $m_a(b) := ab$, you are actually dealing with $m_{a, b}(c) := acb$ (of which my answer would be a special case).

Ah yes makes sense, thank you.
